# Calculating if user is over 16 years old with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I'm making a form with a date input and a following textbox. I want the text box to become enabled if the user has selected a birthday that is less than 16 years old.

So far I have:

```
function checkAge() {
    var birthDate = document.getElementById("DoB");
    var today = new Date();

    if (today >= new Date(birthDate.getFullYear() + 16, birthDate.getMonth(), birthDate.getDate())) {
        // Member over 16, keep parent/guardian textbox disabled.
        document.getElementById("parentConsent").disable = true;
    } else {
        // Require Parent/Guardian permission
        document.getElementById("parentConsent").disable = false;
        document.getElementById("parentConsent").setAttribute('required');
    }
}
```

Here's my current JsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n3d9mLey/

Comment: I'd just always `return true` seeming as no-one under the age of 16 would actually admit to it on the Internet if it meant being denied access to a website.

Comment: This one I would suspect they have to be honest as it would be a face to face fitness sign-up and under 16 will still be allowed to sign up

Comment: I see your JsFiddle. Note that `<input type="date" />` is not widely supported by desktop browsers. You're better-off with indpendent `<select>` elements for day, month and year separately.

Comment: gotcha, that makes sense - so you're not writing an agewall for a nudie site then :D

Comment: BTW, your jsFiddle doesn't work because you've set it to wrap the code in `onLoad`, change the sidebar option to "No wrap".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the dom element directly for calculating the date, you can try something like this

```
function checkAge() {
    var birthDate = new Date(document.getElementById("DoB").value);
    var today = new Date();

    if (today >= new Date(birthDate.getFullYear() + 16, birthDate.getMonth(), birthDate.getDate())) {
        // Member over 16, keep parent/guardian textbox disabled.
        document.getElementById("parentConsent").disable = true;
    } else {
        // Require Parent/Guardian permission
        document.getElementById("parentConsent").disable = false;
        document.getElementById("parentConsent").setAttribute('required');
    }
}
```